# Is it possible to sticky an overflowed HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The CSS element `position: sticky` is supported by most modern web browsers. But some browsers still in common use, notably IE11, don't support it.

To get round this there are various javascript solutions such as Stickyfill and Stickybits. None that I can find, however, will work on an element with its overflow set.

I'm trying to sticky an element that's nested inside one which has:

```
#content {
    position: fixed;
    top: 120px;
    bottom: 80px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 4;
}
```

The `position: sticky` CSS works fine to stick the child element, but the sticky javascript does not. Removing either `position: fixed` or `overflow: auto` makes the sticky work in IE11 but it also completely breaks the layout.

There's a rough reproduction of the issues in [this JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y3e058tf/2/).

I presume the lack of support for this in sticky JS libraries means it's likely impossible, but I wanted to be sure. Is there a way of getting both to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this solution from [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/css-position-sticky-introduction-polyfills/).
You can check if the browser support the `position: sticky` and add the fixed position with `@support` feature detection.

```js
var menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
var menuPosition = menu.getBoundingClientRect();
var placeholder = document.createElement('div');
placeholder.style.width = menuPosition.width + 'px';
placeholder.style.height = menuPosition.height + 'px';
var isAdded = false;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    if (window.pageYOffset >= menuPosition.top && !isAdded) {
        menu.classList.add('sticky');
        menu.parentNode.insertBefore(placeholder, menu);
        isAdded = true;
    } else if (window.pageYOffset < menuPosition.top && isAdded) {
        menu.classList.remove('sticky');
        menu.parentNode.removeChild(placeholder);
        isAdded = false;
    }
});
```

```css
body {
   margin: 0; 
}

.header {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #ddcbaf;
    text-align: center;
}

.header h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #BFFFF3;
}

.menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 25%;
}

.menu li:hover,
.menu li:focus {
    background-color: #66FFE3;
}

.menu a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sticky {
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
}

.container {
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: #989898;
}
```

```html
 <div class="header">
    <h1>My big company!</h1>
  </div>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li><li>
    <a href="#">Services</a></li><li>
    <a href="#">Portfolio</a></li><li>
    <a href="#">About</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent luctus urna sit amet sollicitudin venenatis. Aenean odio tortor, varius vitae molestie eu, ultricies vel lacus. Nam viverra fermentum dapibus. Nulla at semper diam. Phasellus sit amet hendrerit sapien, non semper felis. Morbi augue leo, mattis nec leo sed, malesuada porta dui. Maecenas pretium eros quis lorem luctus gravida.</p>

    <p>Sed gravida quam odio, euismod accumsan mauris ornare quis. Duis sed condimentum justo. Phasellus ac dui eget velit bibendum viverra. Aenean porttitor commodo diam, quis interdum mi sagittis lobortis. Donec id ipsum dignissim, pharetra nunc sit amet, porttitor elit. Donec iaculis elit et enim interdum, ac laoreet lorem consequat. Sed eu elit ut quam pellentesque cursus. Integer sed condimentum est. Integer tempor placerat bibendum. Sed ut semper arcu, at porttitor nibh. Fusce vulputate pharetra tellus a laoreet. Cras imperdiet enim sed turpis adipiscing placerat. Vestibulum ut rhoncus mauris. In egestas ullamcorper dolor vitae suscipit. Curabitur non orci rutrum, iaculis ligula quis, sollicitudin neque. Aliquam dapibus dignissim tincidunt.</p>

    <p>Suspendisse at urna mauris. Vivamus eu lectus et quam viverra accumsan quis nec ligula. Aliquam sed mi sit amet arcu convallis bibendum id eu lorem. Sed pretium eget nibh egestas consectetur. Sed adipiscing, libero sed molestie laoreet, arcu tortor elementum ligula, nec commodo ipsum augue ut tellus. Morbi nibh mauris, facilisis vel bibendum vehicula, dignissim in tortor. Suspendisse augue urna, vestibulum at orci nec, scelerisque cursus mi. Proin congue eget justo et mattis.</p>

    <p>Suspendisse suscipit in lectus at aliquet. Integer non sem enim. Vestibulum aliquam imperdiet laoreet. In malesuada sodales augue, ut aliquam elit tempus id. Suspendisse sed hendrerit nibh. Curabitur molestie in libero nec vulputate. Cras ut scelerisque lacus, vitae cursus dui. Fusce ultricies lectus tincidunt, congue elit interdum, pellentesque nunc.</p>
    <p>Donec quis diam dapibus, accumsan ipsum vitae, porta turpis. Pellentesque vel ligula suscipit, scelerisque justo sit amet, vestibulum enim. Morbi eget sapien blandit, mattis enim sed, tincidunt eros. Nullam urna lectus, pretium id ultrices non, convallis vitae arcu. Fusce vel justo in nulla pulvinar interdum id sed sem. Ut quis ullamcorper dolor, a bibendum quam. Vivamus pellentesque, enim feugiat tempus venenatis, arcu quam molestie eros, quis bibendum nulla metus vitae nisi. Integer at lectus at metus eleifend molestie. Nulla sit amet pharetra est. Sed commodo ac leo ac volutpat. Vivamus enim sapien, sodales vel cursus sit amet, ornare at risus. Proin a lacus id felis aliquet fringilla.</p>

    <p>Donec quis diam dapibus, accumsan ipsum vitae, porta turpis. Pellentesque vel ligula suscipit, scelerisque justo sit amet, vestibulum enim. Morbi eget sapien blandit, mattis enim sed, tincidunt eros. Nullam urna lectus, pretium id ultrices non, convallis vitae arcu. Fusce vel justo in nulla pulvinar interdum id sed sem. Ut quis ullamcorper dolor, a bibendum quam. Vivamus pellentesque, enim feugiat tempus venenatis, arcu quam molestie eros, quis bibendum nulla metus vitae nisi. Integer at lectus at metus eleifend molestie. Nulla sit amet pharetra est. Sed commodo ac leo ac volutpat. Vivamus enim sapien, sodales vel cursus sit amet, ornare at risus. Proin a lacus id felis aliquet fringilla.</p>

    <p>Donec quis diam dapibus, accumsan ipsum vitae, porta turpis. Pellentesque vel ligula suscipit, scelerisque justo sit amet, vestibulum enim. Morbi eget sapien blandit, mattis enim sed, tincidunt eros. Nullam urna lectus, pretium id ultrices non, convallis vitae arcu. Fusce vel justo in nulla pulvinar interdum id sed sem. Ut quis ullamcorper dolor, a bibendum quam. Vivamus pellentesque, enim feugiat tempus venenatis, arcu quam molestie eros, quis bibendum nulla metus vitae nisi. Integer at lectus at metus eleifend molestie. Nulla sit amet pharetra est. Sed commodo ac leo ac volutpat. Vivamus enim sapien, sodales vel cursus sit amet, ornare at risus. Proin a lacus id felis aliquet fringilla.</p>

    <p>Donec quis diam dapibus, accumsan ipsum vitae, porta turpis. Pellentesque vel ligula suscipit, scelerisque justo sit amet, vestibulum enim. Morbi eget sapien blandit, mattis enim sed, tincidunt eros. Nullam urna lectus, pretium id ultrices non, convallis vitae arcu. Fusce vel justo in nulla pulvinar interdum id sed sem. Ut quis ullamcorper dolor, a bibendum quam. Vivamus pellentesque, enim feugiat tempus venenatis, arcu quam molestie eros, quis bibendum nulla metus vitae nisi. Integer at lectus at metus eleifend molestie. Nulla sit amet pharetra est. Sed commodo ac leo ac volutpat. Vivamus enim sapien, sodales vel cursus sit amet, ornare at risus. Proin a lacus id felis aliquet fringilla.</p>

    <p>Donec quis diam dapibus, accumsan ipsum vitae, porta turpis. Pellentesque vel ligula suscipit, scelerisque justo sit amet, vestibulum enim. Morbi eget sapien blandit, mattis enim sed, tincidunt eros. Nullam urna lectus, pretium id ultrices non, convallis vitae arcu. Fusce vel justo in nulla pulvinar interdum id sed sem. Ut quis ullamcorper dolor, a bibendum quam. Vivamus pellentesque, enim feugiat tempus venenatis, arcu quam molestie eros, quis bibendum nulla metus vitae nisi. Integer at lectus at metus eleifend molestie. Nulla sit amet pharetra est. Sed commodo ac leo ac volutpat. Vivamus enim sapien, sodales vel cursus sit amet, ornare at risus. Proin a lacus id felis aliquet fringilla.</p>

    <p>Donec quis diam dapibus, accumsan ipsum vitae, porta turpis. Pellentesque vel ligula suscipit, scelerisque justo sit amet, vestibulum enim. Morbi eget sapien blandit, mattis enim sed, tincidunt eros. Nullam urna lectus, pretium id ultrices non, convallis vitae arcu. Fusce vel justo in nulla pulvinar interdum id sed sem. Ut quis ullamcorper dolor, a bibendum quam. Vivamus pellentesque, enim feugiat tempus venenatis, arcu quam molestie eros, quis bibendum nulla metus vitae nisi. Integer at lectus at metus eleifend molestie. Nulla sit amet pharetra est. Sed commodo ac leo ac volutpat. Vivamus enim sapien, sodales vel cursus sit amet, ornare at risus. Proin a lacus id felis aliquet fringilla.</p>

    <p>Donec quis diam dapibus, accumsan ipsum vitae, porta turpis. Pellentesque vel ligula suscipit, scelerisque justo sit amet, vestibulum enim. Morbi eget sapien blandit, mattis enim sed, tincidunt eros. Nullam urna lectus, pretium id ultrices non, convallis vitae arcu. Fusce vel justo in nulla pulvinar interdum id sed sem. Ut quis ullamcorper dolor, a bibendum quam. Vivamus pellentesque, enim feugiat tempus venenatis, arcu quam molestie eros, quis bibendum nulla metus vitae nisi. Integer at lectus at metus eleifend molestie. Nulla sit amet pharetra est. Sed commodo ac leo ac volutpat. Vivamus enim sapien, sodales vel cursus sit amet, ornare at risus. Proin a lacus id felis aliquet fringilla.</p>

    <p>Donec quis diam dapibus, accumsan ipsum vitae, porta turpis. Pellentesque vel ligula suscipit, scelerisque justo sit amet, vestibulum enim. Morbi eget sapien blandit, mattis enim sed, tincidunt eros. Nullam urna lectus, pretium id ultrices non, convallis vitae arcu. Fusce vel justo in nulla pulvinar interdum id sed sem. Ut quis ullamcorper dolor, a bibendum quam. Vivamus pellentesque, enim feugiat tempus venenatis, arcu quam molestie eros, quis bibendum nulla metus vitae nisi. Integer at lectus at metus eleifend molestie. Nulla sit amet pharetra est. Sed commodo ac leo ac volutpat. Vivamus enim sapien, sodales vel cursus sit amet, ornare at risus. Proin a lacus id felis aliquet fringilla.</p>

    <p>Donec quis diam dapibus, accumsan ipsum vitae, porta turpis. Pellentesque vel ligula suscipit, scelerisque justo sit amet, vestibulum enim. Morbi eget sapien blandit, mattis enim sed, tincidunt eros. Nullam urna lectus, pretium id ultrices non, convallis vitae arcu. Fusce vel justo in nulla pulvinar interdum id sed sem. Ut quis ullamcorper dolor, a bibendum quam. Vivamus pellentesque, enim feugiat tempus venenatis, arcu quam molestie eros, quis bibendum nulla metus vitae nisi. Integer at lectus at metus eleifend molestie. Nulla sit amet pharetra est. Sed commodo ac leo ac volutpat. Vivamus enim sapien, sodales vel cursus sit amet, ornare at risus. Proin a lacus id felis aliquet fringilla.</p>

    <p>Donec quis diam dapibus, accumsan ipsum vitae, porta turpis. Pellentesque vel ligula suscipit, scelerisque justo sit amet, vestibulum enim. Morbi eget sapien blandit, mattis enim sed, tincidunt eros. Nullam urna lectus, pretium id ultrices non, convallis vitae arcu. Fusce vel justo in nulla pulvinar interdum id sed sem. Ut quis ullamcorper dolor, a bibendum quam. Vivamus pellentesque, enim feugiat tempus venenatis, arcu quam molestie eros, quis bibendum nulla metus vitae nisi. Integer at lectus at metus eleifend molestie. Nulla sit amet pharetra est. Sed commodo ac leo ac volutpat. Vivamus enim sapien, sodales vel cursus sit amet, ornare at risus. Proin a lacus id felis aliquet fringilla.</p>

    <p>Donec quis diam dapibus, accumsan ipsum vitae, porta turpis. Pellentesque vel ligula suscipit, scelerisque justo sit amet, vestibulum enim. Morbi eget sapien blandit, mattis enim sed, tincidunt eros. Nullam urna lectus, pretium id ultrices non, convallis vitae arcu. Fusce vel justo in nulla pulvinar interdum id sed sem. Ut quis ullamcorper dolor, a bibendum quam. Vivamus pellentesque, enim feugiat tempus venenatis, arcu quam molestie eros, quis bibendum nulla metus vitae nisi. Integer at lectus at metus eleifend molestie. Nulla sit amet pharetra est. Sed commodo ac leo ac volutpat. Vivamus enim sapien, sodales vel cursus sit amet, ornare at risus. Proin a lacus id felis aliquet fringilla.</p>

    <p>Donec quis diam dapibus, accumsan ipsum vitae, porta turpis. Pellentesque vel ligula suscipit, scelerisque justo sit amet, vestibulum enim. Morbi eget sapien blandit, mattis enim sed, tincidunt eros. Nullam urna lectus, pretium id ultrices non, convallis vitae arcu. Fusce vel justo in nulla pulvinar interdum id sed sem. Ut quis ullamcorper dolor, a bibendum quam. Vivamus pellentesque, enim feugiat tempus venenatis, arcu quam molestie eros, quis bibendum nulla metus vitae nisi. Integer at lectus at metus eleifend molestie. Nulla sit amet pharetra est. Sed commodo ac leo ac volutpat. Vivamus enim sapien, sodales vel cursus sit amet, ornare at risus. Proin a lacus id felis aliquet fringilla.</p>
    <p>Donec quis diam dapibus, accumsan ipsum vitae, porta turpis. Pellentesque vel ligula suscipit, scelerisque justo sit amet, vestibulum enim. Morbi eget sapien blandit, mattis enim sed, tincidunt eros. Nullam urna lectus, pretium id ultrices non, convallis vitae arcu. Fusce vel justo in nulla pulvinar interdum id sed sem. Ut quis ullamcorper dolor, a bibendum quam. Vivamus pellentesque, enim feugiat tempus venenatis, arcu quam molestie eros, quis bibendum nulla metus vitae nisi. Integer at lectus at metus eleifend molestie. Nulla sit amet pharetra est. Sed commodo ac leo ac volutpat. Vivamus enim sapien, sodales vel cursus sit amet, ornare at risus. Proin a lacus id felis aliquet fringilla.</p>

    <p>Donec quis diam dapibus, accumsan ipsum vitae, porta turpis. Pellentesque vel ligula suscipit, scelerisque justo sit amet, vestibulum enim. Morbi eget sapien blandit, mattis enim sed, tincidunt eros. Nullam urna lectus, pretium id ultrices non, convallis vitae arcu. Fusce vel justo in nulla pulvinar interdum id sed sem. Ut quis ullamcorper dolor, a bibendum quam. Vivamus pellentesque, enim feugiat tempus venenatis, arcu quam molestie eros, quis bibendum nulla metus vitae nisi. Integer at lectus at metus eleifend molestie. Nulla sit amet pharetra est. Sed commodo ac leo ac volutpat. Vivamus enim sapien, sodales vel cursus sit amet, ornare at risus. Proin a lacus id felis aliquet fringilla.</p>

    <p>Donec quis diam dapibus, accumsan ipsum vitae, porta turpis. Pellentesque vel ligula suscipit, scelerisque justo sit amet, vestibulum enim. Morbi eget sapien blandit, mattis enim sed, tincidunt eros. Nullam urna lectus, pretium id ultrices non, convallis vitae arcu. Fusce vel justo in nulla pulvinar interdum id sed sem. Ut quis ullamcorper dolor, a bibendum quam. Vivamus pellentesque, enim feugiat tempus venenatis, arcu quam molestie eros, quis bibendum nulla metus vitae nisi. Integer at lectus at metus eleifend molestie. Nulla sit amet pharetra est. Sed commodo ac leo ac volutpat. Vivamus enim sapien, sodales vel cursus sit amet, ornare at risus. Proin a lacus id felis aliquet fringilla.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I couldn't use this directly, as my menu is floating to the right. But it's helped me engineer a stopgap solution, so ... tick.