# Sticky header in IE

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, internet-explorer

I have a project in Angular 4 and I need to do sticky header. Everything is good when I'm using `position: sticky` but `sticky` doesn't work on IE.

1.) I created component with good method (I know that I can simplify if loops but it's not important now):

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
  checkScroll() {
    if(window.pageYOffset >= 200){
      this.isSticky = true;
      this.isNonSticky = false;
    }
    if(window.pageYOffset < 200){
      this.isSticky = false;
      this.isNonSticky = true;
    }
  }
```

2.) I have view in html with different div's and I have one div with ngClass:

```
[ngClass]="{ 'summary-row': isNonSticky, 'sticky' : isSticky}"
```

which should be sticky when window.pageYOffset is bigger or equal 200 pixels.

3.) I have a CSS too like below for my div:

```
.summary-row {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 30px;
  padding-right: 100px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: brown;
  top: 70px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

When I'm scrolling down I see my sticky header but he's blinking.
I have some theory but I don't know if I'm right.

This div is in the middle like:

[image: div grid]

When I'm setting `position: fixed;` I know that this element is removed from the normal document flow [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) so I think because of that I have different pageYOffset (less than 200 px) so that's why I see blinking.
Can someone explain if I'm right? If it's the truth what can I do to do it right?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with the only above code. You could provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to show us the "blinking sticky header". Besides, I found a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48790932/is-it-possible-to-sticky-an-overflowed-html-element) about using sticky header in IE. You could refer to the solution in the thread, it works well in IE. You could also refer to [the origin article](https://www.sitepoint.com/css-position-sticky-introduction-polyfills/) for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything was ok except height. I had to set height for `mydiv` and it worked.